# android tv app with live satellite channels

Tags: android, channel, android-tv, television

A friend asked me to make an app for a TV that shows some information on one halve of the TV and on the other halve he wants to put some TV channel. My question is if it is possible to create an app that does that for android TV. Showing on half of the screen a TV channel and on the other half some information.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is possible.
If you want to make TV application, Google encourages you to use Tv Input Framework [TIF](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/).

It consists of 2 parts: service which acquires channels from cable and application which binds to that service and shows channels lists.

You can use Leanback library by Google:
[leanback](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback)

EDIT:
Example of TIF service:
[TIF service commectial app example](https://github.com/iWedia/iWediaSimpleTvInputService/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/iwedia/example/tvinput/TvService.java)

Comment: due you now some place where I can an example of implementation of the code?

Comment: Yes, I worked on something similar in my company. Project is open source, so you can find details here https://github.com/iWedia/iWediaSimpleTvInputService

Comment: witch Programm was used to develop the project? Because Im only familiar with eclipse or Titanium. But for native Android development I prefere eclipse

Comment: You should switch to Android Studio. Eclipse ADT plugin is deprecated and you should not use it anymore. You will find easy to switch, Android studio is very good for both native and Java.

Comment: I now that I have to change. So was this project developed with Android Studio?

Comment: Yes it is. You can see that by taking a look to a root of the project. If gradle is used, then Android studio is the used IDE.

Comment: Thanks. I will explore the project with android studio

Comment: Okay. Mark my answer as solution if it helps you.

Comment: Just one mor question. How can I teste my project? Withs emulator should I use?

Comment: You should make emulator with TV image. You have 3 kinds: tv, tablet and phone. Use TV.